# Using HasMaxLength on a string with a non-unicode convention is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

I wrote the following custom convention in Entity Framework 6:

```
public class NonUnicodeConvention : Convention
{        
    public NonUnicodeConvention()
    {
        this.Properties<string>()
            .Configure(property => property.IsUnicode(false));
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Configurations
    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // Conventions        
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new NonUnicodeConvention());
}
```

When I add a string property without doing any configuration, the migration that gets created looks like this:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.SomeTable",
         c => new
         {
             Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
             Name= c.String(unicode: false)
         })
         .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

This is exactly what I want...but it seems as soon as I use the HasMaxLength on a specific field it no longer makes it unicode:

```
Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(128);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.SomeTable",
         c => new
         {
             Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
             Name= c.String(maxLength: 128)
         })
         .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

It seems something is overwriting the unicode convention in this case. I wanted the unicode convention so I didn't have to specify it in every case, but whenever I use HasMaxLength it seems to get overwritten. Am I doing something wrong?

I should not that if I use any of the other string specific configurations such as IsFixedLength or IsRequired it does not change the unicode property.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @cb3431 Unfortunately I did not. I have had to manually configure it for each string property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [fixed](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1665) in Entity Framework 6.1.

> Closed Jan 23 at 3:52 PM by lukew
>   Verified that setting MaxLength no longer sets the IsUnicode property on strings. This fixes interactions between string conventions that set IsUnicode and configurations of the string MaxLength.